# rack variables not showing up

Tags: ruby, rack

rack.request.form_input isn't in my env variable--what's going on?

anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rack::Utils to parse the incoming request's body (otherwise form_input is not created).

Comment: What part of Rack::Utils should I use?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It was `Rack::Request`. Do a `Rack::Request.new(env).POST` once and it will set `rack.request.form_input`, `rack.request.form_hash` and `rack.request.form_vars`